# How to filter object from Realm database in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have realm array and I want to filter objects that contain id = 2 and user_id = 4. Please review my code below.

```
 for item in realm.objects(data.self).filter("id == 2 && user_id == 4") {
   print(item)
  }
```

Comment: Does that even compile? You're missing a `"`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have added a ", it's by mistake

Comment: You change second `id` to `user_id` after two answers added? It's not normal! Please, always check your question before post!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator in a realm, please check my answer below.

```
for item in realm.objects(data.self).filter("id == 2 AND user_id == 4") {
   print(item)
}
```

Comment: `AND` leads to wrong logic. Should be `OR`, probably?

Comment: how to use || operator in Realm

Comment: @InderpalSingh, never mind. Author change the question and your answer almost correct.

Comment: @InderpalSingh Can't understand how it works for you, it should even return an empty array!

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the `id` with equality simultaneously with tow values seems to be *not* logical, `id` *always* has ONE value (2 OR 4) but not both, which means that your code should always return an empty array.

If you are aiming to filter the objects based on the value of `id` if its 2 or 4, you could do it like this:

```
for item in realm.objects(data.self).filter("id == 2 OR id == 4") {
   print(item)
}
```

*Note that in the predicate you should type "AND" instead of "&&" and "OR" instead of "||". For more details, check: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering*

which means that `item` would be any item that its `id` is 2 or 4.

---

**Update:**

Because of the change of the predicate from:

```
"id == 2 OR id == 4"
```

to

```
"id == 2 && user_id == 4"
```

What you should simply do -as I mentioned in the above note- is to change "&&" to "AND":

```
for item in realm.objects(data.self).filter("id == 2 AND user_id == 4") {
   print(item)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for item in realm.objects(data.self).filter("id = %@ OR id == %@",2,4) {
  print(item)
}
```